# How does Stack Overflow real-time updates work?

Tags: discussion, web-sockets

How does Stack Overflow fetch updates regarding posts?

For example, whenever someone updates their answer or the author changes the question, you'll see notifications on the screen like this post has a new comment or edit. How does it work? Is it based on websockets? Does the same websocket connection for the same post, which is open on-screen with all the users, have bidirectional updates for that post?

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343/how-do-the-stack-exchange-websockets-work-what-are-all-the-options-you-can-send and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network/10370#10370 and https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/03/stack-overflow-a-technical-deconstruction/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. Stack Exchange uses a WebSocket connection once the page is loaded to get near real-time updates. You can test this your self in your browser as shown in [How do the Stack Exchange WebSockets work? What are all the options you can send to them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343)

```
var w = new WebSocket("ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/"); 
w.onmessage = function(e) { 
    data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    data.data = JSON.parse(data.data)
    console.log(data) 
}; 
w.onopen = function() { 
    w.send("155-questions-active") 
};
```

The socket is not bi-directional. It is opened by your browser, subscribes to one or more messages and then waits for the messages to arrive. No messages are send from the client to the server after that.

For this particular question these are the WebSocket messages that are being send:

[image: 4 websocket messages]

The post I linked to lists all known/observed/reverse engineered messages you can send on the WebSocket.

The WebSocket feature was added in 2012, 4 years after Stack Overflow was launched: [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

Given the scale of Stack Overflow performance is always a concern. The developer team therefor initially designed and build their own WebSocket server implementation. The source code is still available on [GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/NetGain) but newer developments made they probably now use out-of-the-box features that come with the newer .Net versions.

Interesting backstories on the technical history of Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange:

- [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369)
- [Architecture blog by Nick Craver (former lead dev)](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/03/stack-overflow-a-technical-deconstruction/)